# Custom font (fontface) not working when published

Tags: html, css, font-face, publisher

I have a custom font in my css.  It works on the local page, but not when I publish the site to a server.  Here is my css:

```
 @font-face{ 
font-family: 'Font-Example';
src: url('example.eot');
src: url('example.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('example.woff') format('woff'),
     url('example.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('example.svg#webfont') format('svg');
 }
 #kay { font-family: 'Font-Example', Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;}
```

and my html:

```
 <span id="kay">Font Example</span>
```

I've tried opening the published site in several browsers, none of them work.  Am I missing something, or is it just not supported no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

If the font works locally but not when on the server then you need to check the path to the font file.
Inspect the page, inspect what it tells you the location path is, compare this to the ACTUAL location path and you should find your issue!

Answer (score 0):

To embed your selected fonts into a webpage, look into the following example html code. Additionally if you are looking to import a no. of good fonts then i will recommend to use https://fonts.google.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fascinate+Inline');

#kay {
    font-family: 'Fascinate Inline', cursive;
    font-size:26pt;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p style="font-family: 'Raleway', serif;">Write Your Beautiful Texts Here</p>


<span id="kay">Your Font Example</span>
</body>
</html>
```

If you still need some guidance then read this helpful article 
https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I can think of two options:

1. According to the CSS code, the files `example.eot`, `example.woff`, `example.ttf` y `example.svg` should be on the same directory of the CSS file, not the HTML one.
2. If you are working on an IIS, you have to configure the `web.config` file.

The code for `web.config` file has to go into the `staticContent` tag.

An example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-truetype"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/x-font-opentype"/>
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```